# How to enable user to add friends via friend's username and display user's friend list in tableview with swift

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift

I'm currently developing iOS App with Swift that users can add friends via username in one view and display user's friend list in another tableview,I'm currently using parse and I'm able to get my app to let user sign up and log in.

I want to know the code of adding friends via username and display user's friend list with parse, 
I've tried looking for this solution and I got nothing but how to get friend list from Facebook which is not related to my app .

Any help is appreciated and Let me know if you need any additional information! ( sorry for my bad english).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the FBSDK for iOS in order to make a graph request for the Facebook friends list.

I don't quite understand if you want to add a "friend" that already is registered in your app or that has a Facebook account, but in any case you'll need to store your users in a data store, i believe Parse has as PFObject which you can save like this:

```
var appUser = PFObject(className:"AppUser")
appUser["userFullName"] = "John Doe"
appUser["userFacebookID"] = 1
appUser["userEmail"] = "j.doe@doe.com"
appUser.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
  (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
  if (success) {
    // The object has been saved.
  } else {
    // There was a problem, check error.description
  }
}
```

From there what you need is to associate the users, with a "Friendship" object for example, like this:

```
var userFriendship = PFObject(className:"Friendship")
    appUser["invitedUserEmail"] = "jane.doe@doe.com"
    appUser["invitingUserEmail"] = "j.doe@doe.com"
    appUser["invitationStatus"] = "pending"
    appUser.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
      (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
      if (success) {
        // The object has been saved.
      } else {
        // There was a problem, check error.description
      }
    }
```

After that you can update the objet in order to change the invitation status to "accepted" or "denied, "cancel" etc.

To get a the list of user invitations and friends you need to make a ParseQuery with the arguments you're looking for, such as:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"invitingUserEmail = 'j.doe@doe.com' AND invitationStatus = 'accepted'"];
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Friendship" predicate:predicate];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
  if (!error) {
    // The find succeeded.
    NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %d friends.", objects.count);
    // Do something with the found objects
    for (PFObject *object in objects) {
        NSLog(@"%@", object.objectId);
    }
  } else {
    // Log details of the failure
    NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
  }
}];
```

You can find a lot more in the Parse Docs here https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide

Comment: Yes I want user to add other users who has already registered in my app and my app didn't include Facebook at anyway.Can you explain more about your code in adding other users and save them in user object.               Very appreciated!.

Comment: Now I understand more but I'm a bit confuse how to link this code to adding user  and show user's friend list. (Sorry for not include this in the top comment)